# Getting table values using collections

Tags: collection

For my custom payment module I have a database table where I need to retrieve data from, but I have issues using collections. 
For example I have a column named "order_id", I load the model that I have in my module and get the collection using `$model->getCollection()`;
What's the correct way to get the data now?

When I use `$collection->getData()["order_id"]`, I get an array with fields like `["order_id"]=> string(9) "145000021".`

How can I get just the value from the table?

Answer (score 1):

A collection returns a collection/list of all found records/items/rows. It doesn't matter if the result is only with one item. So you have to use `foreach` to iterate over the collection result, i.e.:

```
$items = $collection->getData();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $order_id = $item->getOrderId();
    //do something with $order_id
}
```

or if you like to get only the first item, you can use directly this:

```
$order_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getOrderId();
```

Comment: Yes I get that, but it return values like string(9) "145000021" instead of 145000021.

Comment: How did you get this? By `echo` or `var_dump` or...? Please paste the `var_dump` result.

Comment: the var_dump result is the array of the selected row of course: array(1) { ["order_id"]=> string(9) "145000021" }

Comment: I can't understand how exactly it returns `string(9) "145000021"` but you can try to cast the result, for example: `(int) $order_id` or `(string) $order_id`.

Comment: Casting doesn't work. The field in the database table isn't even a string.

Comment: nevermind I think I figured it out. Didn't realize that I wasn't using echo so var_dump gave me the additional information about the datatype.